# dpkg alternative to opkg depends

Tags: linux, debian, openwrt, dpkg, opkg

In opkg (package manager in OpenWRT) I can get dependents pages of some package. For example

command

```
opkg depends vsftpd
```

will outptut

```
vsftpd depends on:
        libc
```

Is there any alternative to this command in dpkg (on Debain)?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80655/how-can-i-check-dependency-list-for-a-deb-package apt-cache showpkg package-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian you can use `apt-cache` to query the package database. There are several ways of getting a list of dependencies, varying in behaviour and output format:

- Print dependencies (name only) for a specific package version:

  ```
  apt-cache depends <pkg_name>[=version|/target_release]
  ```
- Print package information (including dependency name+version) for each available package version:

  ```
  apt-cache showpkg <pkg_name>
  ```
- Print human readable package information for each available package version:

  ```
  apt-cache show <pkg_name>[=version|/target_release]
  ```

---

Consult `man apt-cache` for full syntax and available command line options (such as `--no-recommends`, `--no-suggests`, `--no-all-versions`).

Consider grepping the output (see examples below) but note that in Debian there are several types of dependency and whilst `apt-get install <pkg_name>` will always try to install ones listed as `Depends:`, it might also try to install ones listed as `Recommends:` (a default behaviour).

---

Example outputs:

- `apt-cache depends vsftpd | grep Depends:`

  ```
    |Depends: debconf
    Depends: <debconf-2.0>
    Depends: init-system-helpers
    Depends: libc6
    Depends: libcap2
    Depends: libpam0g
    Depends: libssl1.0.0
    Depends: libwrap0
    Depends: adduser
    Depends: dialog
    Depends: libpam-modules
    Depends: netbase
  ```
- `apt-cache showpkg vsftpd | grep -A1 Dependencies:`

  ```
  Dependencies:
  3.0.3-5 - debconf (18 0.5) debconf-2.0 (0 (null)) init-system-helpers (2 1.18~) libc6 (2 2.15) libcap2 (2 1:2.10) libpam0g (2 0.99.7.1) libssl1.0.2 (2 1.0.2d) libwrap0 (2 7.6-4~) adduser (0 (null)) libpam-modules (0 (null)) netbase (0 (null)) logrotate (0 (null)) ssl-cert (0 (null)) ftp-server (0 (null)) ftp-server (0 (null))
  ```
- `apt-cache show vsftpd | grep Depends:`

  ```
  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~), libc6 (>= 2.15), libcap2 (>= 1:2.10), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libssl1.0.2 (>= 1.0.2d), libwrap0 (>= 7.6-4~), adduser, libpam-modules, netbase
  ```

Comment: `apt-cache depends vsftpd | grep Depends | grep -o '[^ ]*$'` works exactly as I want. Thank you very much for help.